# PHP oldest path based on a dir name

Tags: php, shell-exec, spl

I have on my linux machine such folder tree structure:
`/dir/yyyy/mm/dd/HH`

e.g.:
`/dir/2014/03/01/08`
`/dir/2014/03/20/09`
`/dir/2014/03/01/10`
`/dir/2014/08/01/10`
`/dir/2014/12/15/10`
`/dir/2015/01/01/14`

I'd like to get in php what path is the oldest, like this:
The oldest path is: `2014-03-01 08`
The newest path is: `2015-01-01 14`

How it can be done?

Comment: fastest? myriad of answers too broad. you'll need to benchmark each possible answer to tell whats fastest

Comment: ok, changed my question

Comment: Gather all of them in an array, use function [`sort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php), pick the first one.

Answer (score 0):

It could be written better but it works

```
 $paths = array(
                 '/dir/2014/03/01/08',
                 '/dir/2014/03/20/09',
                 '/dir/2014/03/01/10',
                 '/dir/2014/08/01/10',
                 '/dir/2014/12/15/10',
                 '/dir/2015/01/01/14',
 );

 $dates = array();

 foreach($paths as $path)
 {
     $matches = array();
     preg_match('#([^\/]+?)\/([^\/]+?)\/([^\/]+?)\/([^\/]+?)\/([^\/]+)#', $path, $matches);
     $dates[$path] = strtotime(sprintf("%s-%s-%s %s:00:00", $matches[2],      $matches[3], $matches[4], $matches[5]));
 }

 asort($dates);

 $dates = array_keys($dates);
 $oldest = array_shift($dates);
 $newest = array_pop($dates);
```

It changes date find by regex to unixtimestamp then sorts it and returns top and bottom value of sorted array.

Comment: you actually need to get those directory names recursively

Comment: I didn't see it mentioned in question. I understood it as flat directory structure. If is so then he can use `RecursiveDirectoryIterator`

Comment: sure the OP could go that route, most likely the OP will ask for this part as well since its just about asking for the whole code, i wish you luck then :)

Comment: These directories are different each day, so they cannot be hardcoded.

Comment: Honestly, you don't know how to read strucutre? Use `glob` or DirectoryIterator and you have array to use function  I wrote above.

Answer (score 0):

Little bit like Pascal style)

```
<?php

$oldest = '';
$newest = '';
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('./dir/'));
foreach ($iterator as $file => $object) {
    if ($iterator->getDepth() === 4) {
        $name = $object->getPath();
        if ($name > $newest) {
            $newest = $name;
        }
        if (empty($oldest) or $name < $oldest) {
            $oldest = $name;
        }
    }
}
var_export([$oldest, $newest]);
```

Result:

```
array (
    0 => './dir/2014/03/01/08',
    1 => './dir/2015/01/01/14',
)
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is loop through each folder and find the directory that has the lowest number. If you have the file paths stored in a database, it can be easier, but from your question it seems like you want to search the folders.

```
<?php

    $base = 'dir';
    $yearLowest = lowestDir($base);
    $monthLowest = lowestDir($yearLowest);
    $dayLowest = lowestDir($monthLowest);

    echo $dayLowest;

    function lowestDir($dir) {
        $lowest = null;
        $handle = opendir($dir);

        while(($name = readdir($handle))) {
            if($name == '.' || $name == '..') {
                continue;
            }

            if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$name) && ($lowest == null || $name < $lowest)) {
                $lowest = $name;
            }
        }

        closedir($handle);
        return $dir.'/'.$lowest;
    }

?>
```